# How do I build tensorflow-directml-plugin for Python 3.11?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, python-3.11

I tried to build a tensorflow-directml-plugin whl for Python 3.11.3, but unfortunately the build instructions from the build.md file only gives me error after error, when I supposedely fixed the one, another error occurres and when I fix that one the previous comes up again. So can anyone help me build the whl file, so that I can simply install this package for Python 3.11.3 ?
https://github.com/microsoft/tensorflow-directml-plugin

Cause I can´t seem to succeed to build a whl file to install using pip, with the instructions they provide. I tried to do it via the build.py file they provide, but as said above I run into issue after issue.

Before anyone asks I wanted to try if tensorflow 2.12.0 with wsl2 and directml-plugin with python 3.11.2 is faster than tensorflow-gpu 2.10.0 in python version 3.10.10.

Comment: Same issue here:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch_directml==0.2.0.dev230426 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch_directml==0.2.0.dev230426